# Admin Menu for New Post

Tags: plugin-development

I am learning WordPress Plugin development. I would like to add a Admin Menu to Create a New Post like below.

[image]

My code is like below.

```
public function admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'News Information', 'News Info', 'manage_options', 'news_info', [$this, 'api_key_page'], 'dashicons-info-outline', 30 );
    add_submenu_page( 'news_info', 'News Information', 'API Key', 'manage_options', 'news_info_page', [$this, 'api_key_page'], 0 );
    add_submenu_page( 'news_info', 'News Information', 'Add News', 'manage_options', 'news_info', 'call_back_function', 1 );
}
```

What should I put inside `call_back_function` ? Is it the right way to create Admin Menu ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to add a custom post type called Tutorial. WordPress handles creating the menu all on its own - all you need to do is register the post type. You can start with something like:

```
<?php
// Use the `init` hook.
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_412823_register_tutorials' );

function wpse_412823_register_tutorials() {
     // Set up arguments for the post type.
     $args = array(
          // There are many arguments, but this will make a bare-minimum post type.
          'public' => true,
          'label'  => 'Tutorials',
     );
     // Finally, register the post type.
     register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );
}
?>
```

You will probably want to add more `$args` to fine-tune things, but just registering your custom post type will give you all sorts of built-in functionality like adding the admin menu item.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine.  `$args = array('public' => true, // What will happen if I make it false ?
     );`

Comment: The developer reference (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) is your best friend for determining what different parameters are available and what all the options do.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine. I would like to show Admin Menu to create New post.
If I use below code, I can see `Add New`. 

$args = [
  'public' => true,
  'label' => 'Tutorials',
];

register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2T1c.png

But if I use below code, I can't see `Add New`. Even I can't see the menu also.

$args = [
  'public' => true,
  'label' => 'Tutorials',
  'show_in_menu' => 'tutorial_info',
];

register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );

How can I see `Add New` with Menu using above code ?

Comment: Why do you need a custom string for `show_in_menu`? Are you trying to make the menu appear somewhere other than the default place? If so, you will need to create that top-level page so it already exists before setting the string to place it inside.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine. I would like to show different string in Menu, that's why I need a custom string for `show_in_menu`. How can I show `Add New` like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj7Ga.png ? Thanks.

Comment: Change the label parameters instead of `show_in_menu`.